# Enable a toggle with a link

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I used [this](http://ironsummitmedia.github.io/startbootstrap-agency/) bootstrap template [git code](https://github.com/IronSummitMedia/startbootstrap-agency/blob/gh-pages/index.html), to build a webpage. In the portofolio , when i click an item, a page shows up. Is there any way to share a link that it will display that pages immediately? I tried this

> www.mypage.com/#portfolioModal1

and many others ways, but they don't work.

Answer (score 0):

In your `agency.js` add this code:

```
var hash = window.location.hash;
if(hash)
{
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: $("a[href='#"+hash+"']").offset().top
    }, 1500, 'easeInOutExpo');
}
```

This will get the hash (`portfolioModal1` for  example) and scroll to the given part of the page.

Note: put it inside the `jQuery.ready()` function.

Your `agency.js` should be:

```
$(function() {
    var hash = window.location.hash;
    if(hash)
    {
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: $("a[href='#"+hash+"']").offset().top
        }, 1500, 'easeInOutExpo');
        event.preventDefault();
    }
    $('a.page-scroll').bind('click', function(event) {
        var $anchor = $(this);
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
        }, 1500, 'easeInOutExpo');
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});

// Highlight the top nav as scrolling occurs
$('body').scrollspy({
    target: '.navbar-fixed-top'
})

// Closes the Responsive Menu on Menu Item Click
$('.navbar-collapse ul li a').click(function() {
    $('.navbar-toggle:visible').click();
});
```

*Comments were excluded*.

Comment: I added the above code to the `agency.js` and when I click www.mypage.com/#portfolioModal1 not only this, but every portfolioModal1,2,3 appears and without the style...